# How to make class variables that are not shared among sub-classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to use variables, which are shared among instances of a class. So, class variables seemed to fit the bill. But also those class variables are shared among sub-classes, which needs to be avoided.

Here's the problem:

```
class Parent(object):
    a=[]

class Child(Parent):
    pass

print(Child.a is Parent.a) # => True # Need to avoid this
```

Here's how I tried to solve:

1. Its possible to just shadow parent's class variable by re-declaring it the Child, but its still possible to delete child's "a" variable, when Child.a again points back to Parent.a .

   ```
   class Parent(object):
       a=[]

   class Child(Parent):
       a=[] # Works, but delete-able.

   print(Child.a is Parent.a) # => False # Works
   del Child.a
   print(Child.a is Parent.a) # => True # Breaks again
   ```
2. Same as prev, but "a" added through metaclass, which is nicer.

   ```
   class meta(type):
       def __new__(cls, name, base, clsdict):
               temp_class = type.__new__(cls, name, base, clsdict)
               temp_class.a=[]
               return temp_class
   class Parent(object):
       __metaclass__=meta

   class Child(Parent):
       pass

   print(Child.a is Parent.a) # => False # Works
   del Child.a
   print(Child.a is Parent.a) # => True # Breaks again
   ```

But none of them solves the "possible to delete Child's class variable" problem.

Is it possible to have some sort of descriptor for class variables, which can make deletion impossible? If not, what would be a good way to solve this?

Comment: Sub-classes can access parent classes variables, It's the default behavior of classes? The whole point of a class is to be an instance (and if subclassed a extension of the instance which by default says that a subclass name-space is shared with the parent.).. Or am i missing something fundamentally in your question, heh :) To re-declare to a parents variable you could potentially create your own `__delete__` function that calls for `self.a = super(Child, self).a` or something?

Comment: I second your logic, but in some cases, it might be necessary to have different namespaces for them. For eg., in this case both parent and child might be instantiated and although child subclass from the parent, they need to have separate class var.

Comment: @Torxed I dont get your __delete__ function thing. Also, you seem to be using instance variables there.

Comment: Adding "Don't delete Child.a" to your class's documentation seems entirely reasonable as part of option 1. Nothing in Python is fool-proof, so don't try to make it so. Option 2 is a good example of over-engineering. Adding a metaclass declaration is no simpler than just defining `Child.a` explicitly while requiring you to define a special metaclass in the first place.

Comment: @chepner In this example, you might call it over-engineering, but consider the case when Parent is defined in a library for public use. Parent uses "a" for storing internal state information, which the user knows nothing about. They would prefer to **just** sub- class it and use as they wish. Instead, if the lib forces user to (for every sub-class of Parent) re-define a set of internal class variables (which the user knows nothing about and is never going to touch directly) to some arbitary (atleast to the user) values, it is just mean.

Answer (score 2):

To make a class attribute private to that class, and not subclasses, prefix it with "__" (two underscores).  This is called a "class-private member" or "class-private reference."

In the following `__update` is in the Mapping class, but not in the subclass.

```
class Mapping:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.items_list = []
        self.__update(iterable)

    def update(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            self.items_list.append(item)

    __update = update   # private copy of original update() method

class MappingSubclass(Mapping):

    def update(self, keys, values):
        # provides new signature for update()
        # but does not break __init__()
        for item in zip(keys, values):
            self.items_list.append(item)
```

From: [Python Classes documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)

Here's the original code.  Note that the Child class doesn't inherit the `__a` attribute from the parent class.

Also note that a `Child` *instance object* doesn't inherit the `__a` attribute, either.  The `__a` attr is private to the Parent and its instances, it's not inherited.

### source

```
class Parent(object):
    __a = []

class Child(Parent):
    def check(self):
        print self.__a  # raises exception, __a is in Parent only, not in self

try:
    print(Child.__a is Parent.__a)
except AttributeError as exc:
    print exc
print
try:
    Child().check()
except AttributeError as exc:
    print exc
```

### output

```
type object 'Child' has no attribute '__a'

'Child' object has no attribute '_Child__a'
```

Comment: “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python.

Comment: I dont see how this solves my problem. Can you post a better example of this in the context of the question?

Comment: @bendtherules thanks for the feedback, I've added an example that relates to the original question

Comment: It doesnt work. What if I access  self.--a from a function in child? Its still the same as Parent's self.--a . It simply restricts using the Parent.--a format. [ - used instead of underscore, because of comment formatting system] Code here - http://pastebin.com/ySjAcjcb

Comment: `self.__a` in a function in Child will raise an exception. It's not the same as Parent's __a, because the Python system did "name mangling" to make it different.

Comment: @shavenwarthog It is just name-mangling at play, so it works when you try to do self.__a in child method, it unmangles the name to -Child--a, whereas you can still access it using Child.-Parent--a. See this ex. http://pastebin.com/A0kdhiVr . Yes your soln works partially, but doesnt work for classmethods, seen in prev comment link.

Comment: Also, because of name-mangling, it becomes less accessible outside the instance methods defined within the class ( becomes dependent on the exact name of the sub-class, which I feel is not nice). Again, this looks like the only soln at hand, so I should probably stop wandering about nicety :)